# Error pack(): 2 arguments unused

Tags: php, pack

I'm getting the following error:

```
  **pack(): 2 arguments unused**
```

The calling code is this:

```
  $start = 31;
  $key = pack('A*', $okey , $start, 32);
```

Why am I getting the error and what does it mean?

Comment: Where did you defined `$okey` ?

Comment: it is defined in my script i add this **, $start, 32 and not work**

Comment: Add error reporting: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` And tell us if you get any

Comment: the same error appears with your line